# SecurityException Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-crash-reporting, crashlytics-android

After integrating Firebase Crashlytics instead of Firebase Crash Reporting I have begun to get some crashes.

I don't know anything about **com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider**. What is it? And it appears on some devices (e.g. Samsung S8)

[image]

This is a stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider from ProcessRecord{422f6718 20494:my.package.name/u0a95} (pid=20494, uid=10095) that is not exported from uid 10008

android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1472)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1426)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider (ActivityManagerNative.java:2937)
android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider (ActivityThread.java:4619)
android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContextImpl.java:2303)
android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContentResolver.java:1452)
android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:446)
android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:405)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcss.zzbcc (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcss.zza (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcth.zzbce (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctg.zzdw (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctg.zzbcf (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctg.zzdw (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdr.zzbz (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.zzbf (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuw.zzcid (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuw.zzcie (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuw.zzcid (Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuy.run (Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:848)
```

Comment: It started happening after upgrading Play Services from 11.4.2 to 11.6.0

Comment: @Anton Cherkashyn Hm, thanks for this explanation. I thought badly about Crashlytics :)

Comment: Same issue here after going to 11.6.0

Comment: Yes, on 11.6.0. I downgraded again to 11.4.2

Comment: Btw, I have sent some email to Firebase team about this problem. I hope we will fix it soon.

Comment: @MaximYudin is there any open ticket by firebase I could follow. Getting the same issue .

Comment: @ila no, I had written them in email support.

Comment: Firebase Support Answer: "The team has a fix that should be included in one of the next two releases."

Comment: Any new about ETA of a version that fixes this problem?

Comment: Not yet, I think it will be better make a downgrade temporary :(

Comment: Anyone know if version 11.6.2 - November 27 fix it?

Comment: I think yes "Streaming uploads that fail validation include the **original error** in their stacktrace."

Comment: I uploaded a new version with 11.6.2 and the error is still there, anyone still has this error?

Comment: Yes, still there. Slightly different obfuscated trace, but still there.

Comment: From Firebase super support "Yep, the fix has been delayed due to additional testing on our end. Thanks for your patience on it!"

Comment: Couple of possible workarounds: 1) remove Firebase Perf or 2) verify that the Play services installed on the device is >= the SDK your app uses via GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() == SUCCESS

Comment: Btw, probably it's interesting to anybody. This problem occurs when the device uses this alternative package for Google Play Services Framework -
 https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/wiki.

Comment: Firebase SDK 11.8.0 has been released today: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20171218, the release note does not say anything related to this bug though.

Comment: From Firebase support "The fix was put into place in GmsCore client jar. If you update that library, then you should be all set. ". I think it fixes in 11.8.0 :)

Comment: hmmm, I still see the crash after updating to 11.8.0 ;(

Comment: I've upgraded to 11.8.0. No I see even more errors :(

Comment: Confirmed: 11.8.0 didn't fix it.

Comment: Same here as well :-/

Comment: Upgraded to 11.8.0, and still gets errors.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace of the crash in 11.8.0?  that would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, it's not a Firebase issue, it's a Play Services issue.

Comment: any update on this? any workaround?

Comment: did you find a solution @MaximYudin?

Comment: @Bruno no, I'm not. Now I try to update to 11.8.0 and will see fresh logs.

Comment: thanks @MaximYudin, I just removed it from my app and implemented facebook analytics instead

Comment: @HuiYu it's the same stack trace in 11.8.0

Comment: @HuiYu https://gist.github.com/maxim-yudin/dc47bb466b9cdc71c579d16ff6440900

Comment: We've got a fix in place which will go out in the next release. In the mean time, a possible workaround is to downgrade to 11.4.2; this exception occurs in both 11.6.0 and 11.8.0 on devices with an old version of Google Play Services.

Comment: @Eric Shieh, good to hear this. Thanks. I'll be waiting for next release.

Comment: @EricShieh.. Thanks for the updated. When can I expect the next release..(because we are partially rolled out to production..)

Comment: Can't give a specific date, but the next release should be publicly available in March.

Comment: It's just awful. 3 months to get bug fixed...

Comment: Same here, waiting for that March fix

Comment: Waiting for the March fix. Hope that will address this issue.

Comment: Would pointing a user to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms to update GPS solve it for them? Or is there a reason these devices haven't updated? I'm seeing it mostly on Samsung Galaxy S7. Very frustrating that these users can't open our app!

Comment: Has anyone tried the 12.0 release to see if that fixes the issues ?

Comment: Hi, yes, this issue should be fixed in 12.0. Thanks for your patience on this.

Comment: @EricShieh thanks a lot :)

Comment: Seems fixed, indeed.

Comment: Not fixed yet  : (

Comment: @EricShieh 
seems the issue is not yet fixed on 15.0.2. We are using Firebase 15.0.2 with Firebase core 16.0.0 and GooglePlayService 15.0.2.

The crash still shows on the firebase console. Mostly occurring on Android 6 and 7

Comment: @Neemay Please post a stack trace. We're confident we've plugged the previous crashes reported. Since Firebase 15.0+ the stack traces should look fairly different. If you're seeing stack traces similar to the above, it means they're coming from an older version.

Comment: @EricShieh I encountered a similar problem on 17.0.0. The stacktrace is put here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249911/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-andr