# Does anyone know what this exception is regarding firebase performance monitoring?

Tags: java, android

```
ncaughtException: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider from ProcessRecord{224a8ab 14907:com.ideacellular.digitalvideo/u0a121} (pid=14907, uid=10121) that is not exported from uid 10012
                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4199)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2239)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1517)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:516)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:474)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcss.zzbcc(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcss.zzbcb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcth.zzbce(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctg.zzbcf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzctg.get(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdr.zzg(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcx.zzbf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuw.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuy.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: what is the version of firebase you are using?

Comment: @pallavi richhariya See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257407/securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-android-gms-phe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same crash in latest firebase version (on 11.6.0). I downgraded to 11.4.2 it started working.

Comment: bt performance monitoring is not working in version lower then 11.6.0

Comment: @pallavirichhariya No, it will work. change version to com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2.

Comment: _A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and Google Play services 11.6.0 or higher_ - from documentation. this version is different

Comment: my emulator is android 7 so wt is the problem

Comment: please help if anyone faced  same issue

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257407/securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-android-gms-phe