# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider from ProcessRecord

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

This is very similar to

[SecurityException Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47257407/securityexception-permission-denial-opening-provider-com-google-android-gms-phe)

But it occurs on firebase version 17.0.0

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gms.phenotype.provider.ConfigurationProvider from ProcessRecord{29c68770 31248:fm.qingting.qtradio/u0a77} (pid=31248, uid=10077) that is not exported from uid 10126
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1559(Parcel.java:1559)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1512(Parcel.java:1512)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider + 3478(ActivityManagerProxy.java:3478)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke + 372(Method.java:372)
       at fm.qingting.common.android.patch.OppoStartServicePatchKt$reflect$newIActivityManagerInstance$1.invoke + 46(OppoStartServicePatchKt.java:46)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke + 397(Proxy.java:397)
       at $Proxy4.getContentProvider($Proxy4.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider + 4850(ActivityThread.java:4850)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider + 2597(ContextImpl.java:2597)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider + 1491(ContentResolver.java:1491)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query + 511(ContentResolver.java:511)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query + 471(ContentResolver.java:471)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzab.zzi(zzab.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzab.zzg(zzab.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzaf.zzp(zzaf.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzae.zza(zzae.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzae.zzl(zzae.java:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzae.get(zzae.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zzp.zza(zzp.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResults.immediatePendingResult(PendingResults.java:5)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzc.zza + 106(zzc.java:106)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzc.zzb + 188(zzc.java:188)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzc.zza + 215(zzc.java:215)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzh.run + 2(zzh.java:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1115(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1115)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 590(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:590)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 818(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere?

Comment: Yes. There's a crash. How to make it not have that crash. Should have been pretty easy to catch.

Comment: If you're still receiving this crash, you should probably contact Firebase support with more details such as device, OS version, etc. I'm no longer with the team, but from what I remember, there were major architectural changes since the original crash you linked to was reported. The fact that the stack trace looks the same means this is very likely the same client code running as in the previous crash, meaning it's from a very old client (e.g. a customer is running an old version of the app with the old SDK).